# PHP passing a variable from HTML to another PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, so im making and admin page which requires to deletes entries from databases, and i cant figure out how to pass the id variable of the post to another php file.

```
echo '<form method="post" action="delete_member_post.php" style="text-align:center;" id="delete_post">';
echo '<p style="text-align:center; font-size:20px;"> <font font-size:20px face="Rockwell" color="#680000"> Select post to delete:</font>';
echo '<select name="delete" form="delete_post">';
for ($z=1; $z<=$text["id"]; $z++)
{
    $c=$c+1;
    echo '<option value="' . $c . '">' . $c . ' </option>';
}
echo '</select> <br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Choice"=>';
echo '</form>';
```

After the loop in the PHP file im echoing $c (based on how many entries the DB has) and its printing my options.

In the other file im using

```
$i = $_POST["$c"];
```

to get the id that had been chosen but all i get is the same error,  Undefined variable and  Undefined index.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have to use the `name` of your select-element as the `key` in the POST array: delete. It would be a pain if you had to look after all possible values in order to access the correct entry in the POST array, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: @msfoster you just blew my mind. i was completely stuck in this for about an hour or so. My mistake was pretty dumb, thanks a lot :D

Comment: I didn't check the question but you don't need to do that **$_POST["$c"]**, just write **$_POST[$c]** and the PHP interpreter will convert it to a string for you (if **$c** is a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST['delete']` will return the `value`  of the option that has been selected in the form.

From what I understand this is what you want, if the user has selected the ID `7`  in the dropdown before submitting the form, `$_POST['delete']`  will contain the value `7` .

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to send final value (count) of variable $c to another file? You should save the value of that variable in a hidden input field after the loop:

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="<?= $c  ?>" />
```

Now you can access it with

```
$i = $_POST["count"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php create a file that will contain the variable and its value, then include that file using `include "file.php"`, then the variable is usable in the file you include file.php.